# How to fix org.mapfish.print.JsonMissingException: attribute [spec.pages[0].mapTitle] missing?

Tags: geoserver, geoext, printing

I've installed GeoServer's map printing module. I've tested that it works by following the instructions [here](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/community/printing/index.html). Now, I'm using GeoExt.PrintMapPanel, and my code is as shown below:

```
var mapPanel = new GeoExt.MapPanel({
        renderTo: "mappanel",
        map: map,
        layers: [wms, gLayer, vector],
        center: new OpenLayers.LonLat(21.0936111111, 7.18805555556),
        zoom: 2.5,
        tbar: toolbarItems,
        bbar: [{
            icon: "img/printer.png",
            tooltip: "Print map",
            handler: function() {
                var printDialog = new Ext.Window({
                    autoHeight: true,
                    width: 350,
                    items: [new GeoExt.PrintMapPanel({
                        sourceMap: mapPanel,
                        printProvider: {
                            capabilities: printCapabilities
                        }
                    })],
                    bbar: [{
                        text: "Create PDF",
                        handler: function() {
                            printDialog.items.get(0).print();
                        }
                    }]
                });
                printDialog.show();
            }
        }]
    });
```

where `printCapabilities` is `http://localhost:8081/geoserver/pdf/info.json?var=printCapabilities`, my local installation. I've written this by following the example [here](http://geoext.org/lib/GeoExt/widgets/PrintMapPanel.html?highlight=print#GeoExt.PrintMapPanel).

However, when I try printing, the following error is shown in GeoServer log: 
`org.mapfish.print.JsonMissingException: attribute [spec.pages[0].mapTitle] missing`. Any idea on how I can solve this will be appreciated.

Comment: You can answer your own question and accept it so this question is marked as answered. Alternatively, I can close it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I sorted this out by adjusting `printProvider` to:

```
var printProvider = new GeoExt.data.PrintProvider({
        url: "http://localhost:8081/geoserver/pdf",
        method: "GET", // "POST" recommended for production use
        capabilities: printCapabilities, // from the info.json script in the html
        customParams: {
            mapTitle: "Printing Demo",
            comment: "This is a simple map printed from GeoExt."
        }
    });
```